# What are some ways to overload Min in order for it to work with user defined expressions?

Tags: function-construction, code-review, upvalues

I have defined `size` to work with discrete size labels:

```
ClearAll[size, S, M, L]
SetAttributes[size, {Listable}]

sizes = size @ {S, M, L};
```

I have endowed `size` with a natural ordering:

```
MapIndexed[TagSet[size, order[#1], #2[[-1]]] &, sizes]
```

such that `SortBy[#, order]& @ RandomSample[sizes]` always evaluates to `{size[S], size[M], size[L]}`.

I would like to overload `Min` (and possibly other related functions in the future, but for the moment I'm interested in `Min`) in order to work with `size`. My solution makes use of `SortBy`:

```
 size /: Min[x__size] := SortBy[{x}, order] // First

 (* random example *)
 BlockRandom[
   Rule[#, Min @@ #] &@RandomChoice[sizes, 3], RandomSeeding -> 125478963]
```

The random example given above evaluates to `{size[L], size[S], size[L]} -> size[S]`.

1. Is there a better way to overload `Min` eg. not using `SortBy`?
2. and more broadly, is there a different way to approach the problem?
3. As an aside, when assigning the natural ordering to `size` I tried attaching definitions (`UpValues`) to `order` instead. That works, but requires some care when handling expressions:

   ```
   Clear[size, order]

   MapIndexed[TagSet[order, {order[#1]}, #2]&, sizes];

   (* sorting example *)
   BlockRandom[
     Rule[#, SortBy[#, order /* List /* First]] &@RandomChoice[sizes, 3], RandomSeeding -> 21648735]
   ```

   The example above evaluates to `{size[S], size[S], size[L]} -> {size[S], size[S], size[L]}`. If `order /* List` is not used, `order[size[_]]` does not evaluate to a number and `SortBy` returns unexpected results.

   My motivation for doing this was

   1. it felt better having `TagSet[order, {order[#1]}, #2]` instead of `TagSet[size, order[#1], #2[[-1]]]` inside `MapIndexed` and
   2. it seems more appropriate to attach a definition about the ordering of `size` to `order` instead of `size` itself. On that note, I figured that perhaps it was more natural to use `Set[{order[#1]}, #2]` instead. Which approach is more robust ie less error prone when the code scales up?

Comment: You can use `MinimalBy` instead of `SortBy` to avoid having to sort the whole array.

Comment: Are `{S, M, L}` the only possible labels, or are you expecting to support more labels with a specific ordering?

Comment: @J.M.'sdiscontentment just the three of them

Comment: ```size /: Min[x__size] := sizes[[Min[Position[sizes, #] & /@ {x}]]]```